# Alocating dynamic array with new keyword crashes

Tags: c++, pointers

I create dynamic array called ***pTab** to contain **n = 10 elements** with **pTab = new int(n)** and my program crashes *(sorry for not sharing the error information)*

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){  


int main(){

int *pTab;

int n=10;

pTab=new int(n);                //SHOULD BE pTab=new int[n]; !!!



for(int i=0;i<=n-1;i++){    
    *(pTab+i)=13;
}



    for(int i=0;i<=n-1;i++){            
    cout << *(pTab+i);
}

delete[] pTab;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your program is crashing because you need to use a debugger to find information.

Comment: Ye, now I see the question like 'why my program is crashing' isn't succesfull, see you next time ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pTab=new int(n);` should be `pTab=new int[n];`

The former allocates one int and initializes it with `n`. The latter allocates an array of `n` int's but does not initialize them.

There is also shortcut syntax for `*(pTab+i)`: `pTab[i]` or `i[pTab]`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it isn't defined as initializing them to 0 ... it might do ...

Comment: @AndyNewman You are right, it default-initializes them, which does nothing for `int`. It has been years since I last used `new` to allocate arrays...

Comment: shldn't it be *(pTab+i): *pTab[i]?

Comment: @lakesh Nope. Built-in `x[y]` is a shortcut for `*(x + y)`.

Comment: is it a C++11 feature? sorry, never knew of that.. can point me to some reference? appreciate it..

Comment: @lakesh It's not a new feature, but few people writes `i[pTab]` in practice.

Comment: @lakesh From C++2003 standard: _The expression E1[E2] is identical (by definition) to *((E1)+(E2))._ Unless `[]` is overloaded. Same applies to C.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin Thanks. Got my concepts mixed up. Apologies. Have already upvoted your answer..

Comment: thanks for the advice. i'll train pointers later this day